# React Native - TouchableOpacity and TextInput is not working inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I have a `ScrollView` which has `TouchableOpacity` and `TextInput` inside.
When I press on them, nothing happens.

I found the solution for `TouchableOpacity` and it was to add `rejectResponderTermination={true}` and it worked.
For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={cameraHandler}
   rejectResponderTermination={true}
>
```

However this does not work for TextInput.

```
<TextInput       
   onChangeText={updateText}
   value={value.text}
   rejectResponderTermination={true}
/>
```

I would like to use the functionality of `rejectResponderTermination` in `TextInput`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: would you mind adding the code for your scrollview as well? Just so we can diagnose why `<TextInput>` is not working

Comment: I have a similar layout and I'm not experimenting that problem, maybe it's something else, I don't think it's really the scrollview

Answer (score 1):

`rejectResponderTermination` is not a prop of `TextInput`. Try removing it.

```
<TextInput       
   onChangeText={updateText}
   value={value.text}
/>
```

A [list of props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) can be found in the official documentation.

If you still want the functionality of `rejectResponderTermination`, currently you would have to build your own.
 This [SlideTextInput](https://gist.github.com/adamski/d16895ded0d4a9e2e7df8594b5e9d3ab) is an example of how you would do it.

Comment: yes but I am looking for a solution similar to `rejectResponderTermination` for `TextInput`. My `TextInput` `onFocus` is not working inside `ScrollView`.

Comment: updated answer for you. there's an example you can follow. Currently, RN is in the works of building `rejectResponderTermination` as a prop for textinput